# jQuery - Validate() and grouping similar form items

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form with three numeric input fields corresponding to the 3 numeric parts of a social security number `XXX-YY-ZZZZ`, something like:

```html
<form id="myForm">
<fieldset>
    <legend>My Sample Form</legend>
    <label><strong>Name:</strong></label><br />
    <input name="name" id="name" />
    <br />
    <label><strong>SSN:</strong></label><br />
    <input name="ssn1" id="ssn1" maxlength="3" size="4">
    <input name="ssn2" id="ssn2" maxlength="2" size="4">
    <input name="ssn3" id="ssn3" maxlength="4" size="4">
    <br />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

When there is no social security number, my error message is being displayed after each text field. Is there a way to group these error messages so that there will be 3 text boxes next to each other and then display only one error message?

Comment: thanks RSolberg. I didn't know about mask(). i ended up adding:

groups: { ssn:"ssn1 ssn2 ssn3"
 }, 

errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if (element.attr("name") == "ssn1" || element.attr("name") == "ssn2" || element.attr("name") == "ssn3" )
       error.insertAfter("#ssn3");
     else
       error.insertAfter(element);
    }

to my validate() function.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than have 3 different fields for the Social Security Number, I'd using a single field that is masked for the ###-##-#### format.

You could then have the single validation rule hit the single input box.

[jQuery Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

```
   $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
```

Here is a code sample using a single field for SSN along with the validate plugin and the masked input plugin...

```
<form id="myForm">
<fieldset>
    <legend>My Sample Form</legend>
    <label><strong>Name:</strong></label><br />
    <input name="name" id="name" />
    <br />
    <label><strong>SSN:</strong></label><br />
    <input name="ssn" id="ssn" />
    <br />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#myForm").validate({
            rules: {
                name: "required",
                ssn: "required",
            },
            messages: {
                name: "Please enter your name!",
                ssn: "Please enter your ssn!"
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: good to hear.  I've used it a couple different times for things like phone number and ssn.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have SSN as a single field?  Currently you have 3 separate text fields for each part of the ssn.

Or, there are various Masked-edit fields that will auto add the dashes into the field for the user.  But this is a case where the user would be accustomed to entering their entire number as apposed to entering it in parts.